# iterate for all combinations

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I am performing an operation where I take mean of two images, one image is fixed and 2nd image I iterate through, how can I do the same operation for all combinations? like

```
mean(img1,img1), mean(img1,img2), mean(img1,img3) ... mean(img2,img1), mean(img2,img2), mean(img2,img3) ... mean(img3,img1), mean(img3,img2)mean(img3,img3)


k=[]

for i in range(image.shape[-1]):
    k = (np.mean(image[:, :, 102], img[:, :, i]))
    result.append(k)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a sequence like so:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

n_images = 4
imsz = 2
images = np.random.normal(size=(n_images, imsz, imsz))

image_combinations = combinations(range(images.shape[0]), 2)
means = []
for combo in image_combinations:
    #print(combo)
    means.append( (images[combo[0],:,:] + images[combo[1],:,:]) /2)
means = np.array(means)
means.shape
```

Now, depending on the number and size of your images, the overhead can be relatively large, but I can't find a way to really vectorize the operation (that would be a significant improvement). Indeed, you could do something like where you do *all* combinations (including with itself and in both directions (1,2), (2,1))  then, you go fetch in this matrix the ones that you want.

```
all_means = (images[:,np.newaxis, :,:] + images[np.newaxis,:,:,:]) /2

image_combinations = combinations(range(images.shape[0]), 2)
relevant_means = []
for combo in image_combinations:
    relevant_means.append(all_means[combo[0], combo[1], :,:])
relevant_means = np.array(relevant_means)
```

The second solution seemed to clock faster by a factor more than 2 with 10 2x2 images. However, the memory footprint is also increased by a factor more than 2, so there is no free meal.

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get the means off all combinations of every two images in the array 'image'. Where the slice `[:, :, i, j]` of 'means' is the average of image i and image j.

```
import numpy as np

image = np.random.randint(0, 5, (2, 2, 3))

means = (image[:, :, None, :] + image[:, :, :, None])/2
```

output:

```
image = 
[[[3 1 3]
  [3 4 4]]

 [[2 2 1]
  [0 3 0]]]

means = 
[[[[3.  2.  3. ]
   [2.  1.  2. ]
   [3.  2.  3. ]]

  [[3.  3.5 3.5]
   [3.5 4.  4. ]
   [3.5 4.  4. ]]]


 [[[2.  2.  1.5]
   [2.  2.  1.5]
   [1.5 1.5 1. ]]

  [[0.  1.5 0. ]
   [1.5 3.  1.5]
   [0.  1.5 0. ]]]]
```